# Difference between create Enumerable or Enumerator using Iterators in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

What is the difference between creating Enumerable or Enumerator using Iterators in C#?
I know that Iterators are used to create a private class that implements Enumerable or Enumerator...

Which way is better to create an enumerable type?

Comment: You're probably referring to iterator blocks. You should read this: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Every type that implements the `IEnumerable` interface should implement a method `GetEnumerator` which returns a type that implements the `IEnumerator` interface. Then having an enumerator you can use the `foreach` statement, which in its essence implements the `iterator` pattern, to traverse the elements of a collection of your custom type.

For further clarification please take a look to the following links:

1. [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. [Iterator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)

So in order to answer to your question, I have to say that we shouldn't try to compare the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`. They both are used together, when we want to use the iterator pattern for a custom type.